# Resolv.conf modification breaks DNS

Tags: debian, dns, mono, c#, resolv.conf

This is an odd one but I seem to be unable to solve it.

I'm creating a visual user interface to modify internet settings on Debian Wheezy (and other debian versions/derivatives that are incidentally compatible).

I want to be able to modify the DNS on the basis of what the user inserts.

[image: the UI]

After "Save" is pressed this code is ran:

```
void SaveDNSButton_event(object obj, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
    {
        //save dns settings
        string s1 = "";
        string s2 = "";

        string toWrite = s1 + s2;
        Console.WriteLine ("=============");
        Console.WriteLine ("Reading from resolv.conf before writing...");
        using (StreamReader confReader = File.OpenText ("/etc/resolv.conf")) {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader (confReader.ReadToEnd ());
            string line;
            toWrite = "";
            while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine ())) {
                if (line.Contains ("nameserver")) {
                    Console.WriteLine (line);
                } else {
                    toWrite += line + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            confReader.Dispose ();
            confReader.Close ();
        }

        s1 = "nameserver " + DNSentry1.Text + ";" + Environment.NewLine;
        s2 = "nameserver " + DNSentry2.Text + ";" +  Environment.NewLine;


        Console.WriteLine ("=============");
        Console.WriteLine ("Writing to resolv.conf");
        Console.WriteLine ("To write: " + toWrite + s1 + s2);

        using (StreamWriter confWriter = new StreamWriter ("/etc/resolv.conf", false)) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Writing...");
            confWriter.Write (toWrite + s1 + s2);
            Console.WriteLine ("Closing file stream...");
            confWriter.Dispose ();
            confWriter.Close ();
        }


        Console.WriteLine ("=============");

        Console.WriteLine ("Opening conf to confirm if it worked");
        if (IsLinux) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Trying to open conf");
            StreamReader file = File.OpenText ("/etc/resolv.conf");
            string s = file.ReadToEnd ();
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            file.Dispose ();
            file.Close ();
        }
    }
```

The relevant part is

```
using (StreamWriter confWriter = new StreamWriter ("/etc/resolv.conf", false)) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Writing...");
            confWriter.Write (toWrite + s1 + s2);
            Console.WriteLine ("Closing file stream...");
            confWriter.Dispose ();
            confWriter.Close ();
        }
```

Wherein I overwrite `resolv.conf` with the filled in DNS info. An example input to this would be something like "8.8.8.8" in the first dialog and "8.8.4.4" in the second.  The output would be...

```
=============
Reading from resolv.conf before writing...
nameserver 192.168.2.101
nameserver 8.8.8.8
=============
Writing to resolv.conf
To write: # Generated by NetworkManager
domain trin-it.local
search trin-it.local
nameserver 8.8.8.8;
nameserver 8.8.4.4;

Writing...
Closing file stream...
=============
Opening conf to confirm if it worked
4
Trying to open conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain trin-it.local
search trin-it.local
nameserver 8.8.8.8;
nameserver 8.8.4.4;
```

If I ping google after this it just says: "unknown host google"

HOWEVER, if I manually go to `resolv.conf` and change the nameservers there it actually resolves just fine. What is up with that?  The only change is that I do it through code instead of just nano `/etc/resolv.conf`, as far as I can tell. Can anyone shed some light on this?

#### TL;DR

Why would editing resolv.conf with code NOT work as opposed to manually editing it? Wouldn't it be the same thing?

Comment: @Christopher I didn't know that, so thanks for the info! Though, that part is generated by networkmanager. My code only replaces the stuff with "nameserver" in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is adding a semicolon to the end of the nameserver line; don't do that.

Comment: Incredible. I just... don't know what to say. I just had a 5 minute session of putting my face in my palms. Works flawlessly. Wasted about 2 days just trying hundreds of other solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! Sometimes it just takes a separate pair of eyes :)